# Refresh problem with onChange event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, onchange, eventhandler

I have an input with an onChange event handler that is refreshing the screen every time I try to type some character inside. I would like to know if any of you guys could give me a hand to solve it.

Here is my code:

```
const HeaderUser: React.FC<TabWrapper> = () => {
const [drawerEmpreendimentosVisible, setDrawerEmpreendimentosVisible] = useState(false);
const intl = useIntl().formatMessage;
const [currentEmpreendimento] = useLocalStorage().createState('currentEmpreendimento');

const [displayRoadmapScreen, setDisplayRoadmapScreen] = useState(false)
const [displayRegisterScreen, setDisplayRegisterScreen] = useState(false);
const [inspector, setInspector] = useState('');
const [roadmap, setRoadmap] = useState('');


const RegisterScreen = () => {

    const handleOk = () => {
        setDisplayRegisterScreen(false);
    };

    const handleCancel = () => {
        setDisplayRegisterScreen(false);
    };


    return (
        <div>
           <Modal
                title="Cadastrar novo roteiro"
                visible={displayRegisterScreen}
               onOk={handleOk}
                onCancel={handleCancel}>
                <b>Roteiro:</b>
                <br />
        //Refreshing issue  <Input type="text"  placeholder="Roteiro"  onChange={e => 
                  setRoadmap(e.target.value)} /><br />
                <b>Inspetor:</b>
                <br />
                <Input type="text" name="inspector" placeholder="Inspetor"  onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)} />
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: Try `<Input type="text"  placeholder="Roteiro"  value={roadmap} onChange={e => 
                  setRoadmap(e.target.value)} />` Also for other to replicate this issue, you can give a link to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you have defined your state outside the RegisterScreen component?
Try defining it within the component.

```
const RegisterScreen = () => {
    
    const [roadmap, setRoadmap] = useState('');
    //rest of code...
```